# std::map size is always one

Tags: c++, g++

I have a problem with the std::map. The following code is used:

```
struct cmp_address {

    bool operator()(unsigned long const a, unsigned long const b) {
        return a == b;
    }
};

void test() {
map<unsigned long,char,cmp_address> data;
int numRows = 1000; //this is the number of rows (or number of IP addresses)
    for (int i=1;i<numRows;i++) {
        struct in_addr inp;
        int res = inet_aton("An IP ADdress", &inp);
        if (res) {
//            address is valid
            unsigned long addr = inp.s_addr;
//            data.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned long,char>(addr, 1)); //doesn't work
            data[addr] = 1; //dowsn't work
        }
    }

printf("Loaded rows=%d\n", data.size()); //size is always=1
};
```

The map has long as key and char as value.
I'm inserting approx 1,2 million key-value pairs in the map, but the size is always 1.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Please give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead of excerpts of your real code.

Comment: Just instantiate the map like this: `map<unsigned long,char> data;`. You don't seem to need a comparison functor.

Comment: `cmp_address` should do `a < b`, not `a == b`.

Comment: @user3286380 In which case there would be no point in using it.

Comment: What debugging have you performed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing a constant string to `inet_aton`, you'll get a constant result, and thus a constant key... so you're just replacing the same entry in the map 1000 times.

If you really want a map with multiple values for the same key, you should use `std::multimap`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your comparator is wrong.**

It is supposed to define a *strict weak ordering* but yours comes closer to the opposite. As such, the `std::map`'s internal algorithms all break down and result in undefined behaviour.

You probably meant:

```
struct cmp_address {
    bool operator()(unsigned long const a, unsigned long const b) {
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

taking inspiration from the fact that the default comparator for `std::map` is `std::less`. In fact, this means you don't need your custom comparator at all.

**Also, you keep inserting the same key over and over again**; it's always the IP address for `"An IP ADdress"`. Maps only have one value per key. Choose `std::multimap`, perhaps, if you want multiple values per key.

Comment: Thank you for the response - this fixed the problem.
And the key is different - I just gave an example.

Comment: @Andrei: It was an example that _completely_ changed the meaning of your program, in precisely the way you were complaining about. So please take more care about constructing your minimal examples in the future! :)